# click on a marker in a map

Tags: robotframework, google-maps-markers

I need to click on a pickup point in a maps but i have used different keywords without success

```
${ho}    Get Horizontal Position    //*[@id="map"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]
${ve}    Get Vertical Position    //*[@id="map"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]
Log To Console    ${ho} ${ve}
Click Element At Coordinates   //*[@id="map"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]   ${ho} ${ve}
```

or
Click Element  xpath=//img[@src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png" and
@tabindex='0']

the xpath is :
//*[@id="map"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[3413]

but the [3413] changes every session.
Any help?
this is the html code :

```
<div title="" role="button" tabindex="0" style="width: 48px; height: 39px; overflow: hidden; 
position: absolute; cursor: pointer; touch-action: none; left: 33px; top: 26px; z-index: 
 65;"> 
<img alt="" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png" draggable="false" 
style="width: 48px; height: 39px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; 
max-width: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Hiya, could you clarify a couple of things? Are you saying you're successful when you have the number correct e.g. if the number is 3414 and the problem is making this dynamic? Or is it even with correct value you still can't locate the element?

Also are you able to view these elements via the automation? Is that how you got the html source or did you get it manually - I've had to run a command to disable map optimization in the past during automation is why I'm asking

Comment: the problem is making the dynamic, when i'm in the same session, with the number, i can click on the marker. And  yes, i can see the elements via automation.. Also we get the marker sending a request via api to google maps